# How to cleanly create duplicate components with different parameters in react native/typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a bunch of components that looks like this:

```
<View>
<Component
   containerStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
   id={"test1"}
   onPress={onPress1}/>
 <Component
   containerStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
   id={"test2"}
   onPress={onPress2}/>
 <Component
   containerStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
   id={"test3"}
   onPress={onPress3}/>
  ...
 </View>
```

How can I create this cleanly in code without manually making a long list of these components?

Comment: One way would be to have an array of parameters and `map` over it.

Comment: You can use map method for your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check: (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). You can use `map` method of Arrays:

```js
...
const elementsProps = [
  {
    containerStyle: {color: 'blue'},
    id: 'test1',
    onPress: onPress1
  },
  {
    containerStyle: {color: 'blue'},
    id: 'test2',
    onPress: onPress2
  },
  {
    containerStyle: {color: 'blue'},
    id: 'test3',
    onPress: onPress3
  },
];
return (
  <View>
    {elementsProps.map((element) => (<Component key={element.id} {...element} />)}
  </View>
);
```

You have to pass additional property: `key`, which is required in order to optimise list. If elements change their order, `key` property helps to move elements in DOM rather than rerendering them from scratch. That's why it's not recommended to use `index` as a key, as it will change for the element when order is changed.

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for but just didn't know how to apply it.